# Typescript return object without null or undefined values

Tags: typescript

We are using a `cleanNullOrUndefined` function in our codebase, which gets rid of keys in an object if the value of the key is null or undefined. This is not well-typed and just returns a `Partial` of the original object which gives some errors in other places.

What we need is to type the function to return the object, with keys that are null or undefined removed and inferred types for the other keys.

Example:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: undefined
}

// Desired return type

interface ReturnType {
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: boolean
}
```

I can't seem to get my head around how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this example:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: undefined
}

type Validate<T> = Pick<T, {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends null | undefined ? never : Prop
}[keyof T]>;

// type Test = {
//     a: 1;
//     b: 'string';
//     c: false;
// }
type Test = Validate<{
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: undefined
}>

const util = <Obj,>(obj: Obj): Validate<Obj> => {
  return 'NOT IMPLEMENTED' as any
}

const result = util({
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: undefined
})

result.a // ok
result.e // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOzYpW)

`Validate` iterates through each object key and checks whether it extends `null | undefined` or not. If yes - return `never`, otherwise - return key name `Prop`. `[keyof T]` - at the and grabs all values from newly created object. `Pick` - in turn obtains again only valid keys from `T`.

Comment: Excellent answer as always Mr. Yossarian, thanks.

Comment: @AndréKrosby Thank you!

Comment: This didnt work when I had a JSON object that contained a value with type `string | null | undefined`.

So i modified your type to this
type Validate<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends null | undefined
  ? never
  : NonNullable<T[Prop]>;
};

Comment: @eBoody thank you, feel free to add your example to my answer

Comment: @eBoody Don't change their code's behavior. Add a second section as needed, or even post your own answer that mentions yossarian's.

Comment: @vera. thank you, did not check behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably half the answer. I wanted to show that you can get the destination object with just one line (chain) of code:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: false,
  d: null,
  e: undefined
};

const dest = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(a => obj[a] !== null && obj[a] !== undefined)
    .reduce((c, a) => { c[a] = obj[a]; return c; }, {});

console.log(dest);
```

But there might be a lot more, just to make the resulting type inferred correctly. The question is - do you really need it? ;)